# Flash does not work with the latest updates

Tags: flash

Flash does not work in any browser. Xubuntu 11.10. I've looked everywhere, I've tried flash-aid, I've placed the flash file manually, nothing works. Midori, chromium, iceweasel, firefox, w/e. Reinstalled many times, rebooted countless ones, I've been trying for three days now.

What am I supposed to do? I am lost. Flash is essential for me. Soon to reach the breaking point and switch.

Running:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i flash

ii adobe-flash-properties-gtk 11.2.202.228-0oneiric1 GTK+ control panel for Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11 
ii adobe-flashplugin 11.2.202.228-0oneiric1 Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11 
rc flashplugin-installer 11.2.202.228ubuntu0.11.10.1 Adobe Flash Player plugin installer
```

Comment: What is the output to `dpkg -l | grep -i flash` ?

Comment: ii  adobe-flash-properties-gtk                                  11.2.202.228-0oneiric1                  GTK+ control panel for Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11
ii  adobe-flashplugin                                           11.2.202.228-0oneiric1                  Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11
rc  flashplugin-installer                                       11.2.202.228ubuntu0.11.10.1             Adobe Flash Player plugin installer

Comment: Is shockwave flash version 11.2 r202 in your about:addons in firefox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems with the new version, the 11.2 one. What I did was this (in a terminal):

1. Downloaded: `wget http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.2.159.1-0natty1_i386.deb`
2. Installed it with `sudo dpkg -i adobe-flashplugin_10.2.159.1-0natty1_i386.deb'
3. And opened `sudo synaptic` to force the version.
   [image: synaptic]

This will do the trick. OR

1. Download http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.2.159.1.orig.tar.gz
2. Copy the `libflashplayer.so` to `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/`

Comment: Your solution worked. :) Thank-you very much.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not the best solution, but it works. Later you might need to install the 11.2 version.

Comment: The first command assumes use of an i386 system. I would add links for amd64, also.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Adobe's flash-plug-in doesn't work anymore for Firefox on Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/adobe-adandons-flash-on-linux/). Have you tried **gnash plug-in** for Firefox ? Or tried installing in Google-chrome(not Chromium)?

Comment: Just patched my Kubuntu last evening and flash is working fine for me. OK, I'm running Kubuntu, not Xubuntu.

Comment: you mean working with Adobe's plug-in? or gnash one?

Comment: Shockwave Flash

    File: libflashplayer.so
    Version: 
    Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

MIME Type  Description  Suffixes
application/x-shockwave-flash  Shockwave Flash  swf
application/futuresplash  FutureSplash Player  spl

Answer (score 0):

The first answer worked for me. I would suggest removing the non-working Flash first.
In Terminal:   sudo apt-get remove flashplayer

Comment: This is better as a comment. Also, please format your code accordingly with backticks around it as follows: `not code \`code\` not code`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Flash 11.2, but Flash 11.1 works, and it's available from 
[adobe's website](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_11.1.102.63_archive.zip). It's quite a big file, but in that zip is a .tar.gz which contains the 11.1 version of libflashplayer.so, which you can copy to /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins. (Then restart firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that wget http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.2.159.1-0natty1_i386.deb gives an error 404 (Seems to be removed from the server)

Only the second solution works :
    Download http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.2.159.1.orig.tar.gz
    Copy the iin libflashplayer.so to /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/

Note that the problem is related to the type of cpu you have. 
dpkg -l | grep -i flash 
ii  flashplugin-installer                  11.2.202.236ubuntu0.12.04.1             Adobe Flash Player plugin installer

11.2.202.236ubuntu0.12.04.1 is working ok on some of my computers, but fails to work on a pc with the following processor-type

cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0 
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD 
cpu family  : 6 
model       : 6 
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) XP 1600+ 
stepping    : 2 
cpu MHz     : 1404.763 
cache size  : 256 KB 
fdiv_bug    : no 
hlt_bug     : no 
f00f_bug    : no 
coma_bug    : no 
fpu     : yes 
fpu_exception   : yes 
cpuid level : 1 
wp      : yes 
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 mmx fxsr sse syscall mmxext 3dnowext 3dnow up 
bogomips    : 2809.52 
clflush size    : 32 
cache_alignment : 32 
address sizes   : 34 bits physical, 32 bits virtual 
power management: ts

Replacing the new library with the older version helps on this type of computer.

See also : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/968759

With the most recent package Firefox did nothing when trying to open video's or Google Streetview. Chromium reported an error in libflashplayer. After replacing the new library with the older one, Firefox is working ok. Chromium gives a warning that the
flashplayer is outdated, but if you ignore this warning Chromium is working ok again.